# Python equivalent to Perls END block to cleanup after exit

Tags: python

I have a script that may take a while to run. I would like it to save some details to a file if it exits with an error.

In Perl, the END block would be the place to do something like that.

What is the Python way to clean up after exiting?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is a *"context manager"*, or possibly the `finally` block on a `try`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be done using the atexit module, as described here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html

```
def savecounter():
    open("counter", "w").write("%d" % _count)

import atexit
atexit.register(savecounter)
```